# Copy Azure block blob to Azure file share?

Tags: azure, azure-blob-storage

How do I copy a block (or page) blob in azure storage to an Azure file share? 
My example code works fine if I download the block blob to a local file, but there does not appear to be a method to download to an Azure file share.  I've looked at the Azure data movements library but there's no example of how to do this.

```
void Main()
{
    string myfile =@"Image267.png";

    CredentialEntity backupCredentials = Utils.GetBackupsCredentials();
    CloudStorageAccount backupAccount = new CloudStorageAccount(new StorageCredentials(backupCredentials.Name, backupCredentials.Key), true);
    CloudBlobClient backupClient = backupAccount.CreateCloudBlobClient();
    CloudBlobContainer backupContainer = backupClient.GetContainerReference(@"archive");
    CloudBlockBlob blob = backupContainer.GetBlockBlobReference(myfile);

    CredentialEntity fileCredentails = Utils.GetFileCredentials();
    CloudStorageAccount fileAccount = new CloudStorageAccount(new StorageCredentials(fileCredentails.Name,fileCredentails.Key), true);
    CloudFileClient fileClient =    fileAccount.CreateCloudFileClient();
    CloudFileShare share = fileClient.GetShareReference(@"xfer");

    if (share.Exists())
    {
        CloudFileDirectory rootDir = share.GetRootDirectoryReference();
        CloudFileDirectory sampleDir = rootDir.GetDirectoryReference("hello");
        if (sampleDir.Exists())
        {
             CloudFile file = sampleDir.GetFileReference(myfile);
//           blob.DownloadToFile(file.ToString());
        }       
    }
}
```

The part that does not work is the commented out line `blob.DownloadToFile`

Any ideas on how I can do this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There is an example in the official docs [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/storage/files/storage-dotnet-how-to-use-files#copy-files): it's used to copy files from file share to blob storage, but you can make a little change to copy from blob storage to file share. I also write a sample code which is used copy from blob storage to file share, you can take a look at it as below.

You can use SAS token(for the source blob or source file) to copy files to blob / or copy blob to files, in the same storage account or different storage account.

A sample code as below(copy blob to file in the same storage account, and you can make a little change if they are in different storage account):

```cs
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    CloudStorageAccount storageAccount = CloudStorageAccount.Parse("connection string");

    var blobClient = storageAccount.CreateCloudBlobClient();
    CloudBlobContainer cloudBlobContainer = blobClient.GetContainerReference("t0201");
    CloudBlockBlob sourceCloudBlockBlob = cloudBlobContainer.GetBlockBlobReference("test.txt");

    //Note that if the file share is in a different storage account, you should use CloudStorageAccount storageAccount2 = CloudStorageAccount.Parse("the other storage connection string"), then use storageAccount2 for the file share.
    CloudFileClient fileClient = storageAccount.CreateCloudFileClient();
    CloudFileShare share = fileClient.GetShareReference("testfolder");
    CloudFile destFile = share.GetRootDirectoryReference().GetFileReference("test.txt");
    
    //Create a SAS for the source blob
    string blobSas = sourceCloudBlockBlob.GetSharedAccessSignature(new SharedAccessBlobPolicy()
    {
        Permissions = SharedAccessBlobPermissions.Read,
        SharedAccessExpiryTime = DateTime.UtcNow.AddHours(24)
    });

    Uri blobSasUri = new Uri(sourceCloudBlockBlob.StorageUri.PrimaryUri.ToString()+blobSas);
    destFile.StartCopy(blobSasUri);

    Console.WriteLine("done now");
    Console.ReadLine();
}
```

it works well at my side, hope it helps.

Comment: Thanks Ivan, that works for me.  The bit I was missing was creating a SAS on the source blob.

Comment: I also need to copy the file to back to a blob in a second pass, reason being is that you have to copy page blobs to a file then back as a block blob in order to set the archive tier in Azure to "archive".

Comment: @Dave, since it works for copying blob to file share, could you please mark it as an answer? thanks. And for another issue, could you please raise a new issue, and let me know the link? Thanks.

Comment: Sorry about that, I thought I had marked as answer.  Done now, cheers.

Answer (score 1):

There are a few samples in [here](https://github.com/Azure/azure-storage-net-data-movement) but in dot net. A non code related alternative would be to use [Azcopy](https://github.com/Azure/azure-storage-azcopy) it would help transfer data from blob to File Shares and vice versa.

External Suggestions:
The following tool called [Blobxfer](https://github.com/Azure/blobxfer) seems to support the transfer but in python.